# How to set background music in Qt Creator 9.0.2 - C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

**I have Qt Creator 9.0.2 and I want to add background music to my little project (game).**

I've added QT += multimedia

I tried following:

```
QMediaPlayer* background_music = new QMediaPlayer();

background_music->setMedia(QUrl(..) // there is no setMedia() member function
```

Then I tried

```
background_music->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/sound.mp3"));

background_music->play()

//after a few tries it ran but no music was heard
```

I don't know what to do
Please help.

Comment: Qt creator is an IDE or rather, a glorified editor. It's just what you use to write your code in, it's not some magical environment that enables sound. It doesn't matter whether you write your code in notepad, Emacs or some other editor. Background music needs something more than your ide.

Comment: Have you added `sounds/sound.mp3` to your projects resources? Have you tried listening to the status signals? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html#setSource